# Check mime type as a String against array of mime types

Tags: php

I have a string that represents the mime type:

```
audio/mpeg
```

And I have an array of mime types to check against:

```
['audio/*', 'video/mp4', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/x-smaf', 'application/vnd.smaf', ... ]
```

I need to check if the mime type as a string is valid based on the mime types in the array.

I can use `in_array` and it works fine but it doesn't work against mime types like 'audio/ogg' because `in_array` doesn't understand that `audio/*` means all audio mime types.

Anyway I could get this working without setting all audio mime types individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a bit weird function, maybe it give you an hint:

```
function mimeMatch($mimetype){

    $mimearr = ['audio/*', 'video/mp4', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/x-smaf', 'application/vnd.smaf'];

    if(in_array($mimetype, $mimearr)) return true;

    $content_type = explode("/", $mimetype);
    if(in_array(reset($content_type) . '/*', $mimearr)) return true;

    return false;
}

//test
$m1 = 'audio/mpeg';
$m2 = 'audioxxx/mpeg';

var_dump(mimeMatch($m1)); //true
var_dump(mimeMatch($m2)); //false
```

demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ccaee7e58173d39e974cd7bdda15416246fdd795

Comment: Excellent idea! Thanks.